# Loop through JSON using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add image by following JSON-

```
json = [{
        "id": 6,
        "name": "rac2 ",
        "shop_id": 4,
        "categories_id": 5,
        "category": "category-5",
        "min_price": 555,
        "max_price": 55656,
        "image": "http://www.shopforshops.com/www/61/files/clothing-racks1.jpg",
    },
    {
        "id": 64,
        "name": "rac32 ",
        "shop_id": 4,
        "categories_id": 5,
        "category": "category-5",
        "min_price": 555,
        "max_price": 55656,
        "image": "http://ohjoy.blogs.com/.a/6a00d8341c6a0853ef019affb2bbfe970c-800wi",
    },
    {
        "id": 643,
        "name": "rac32 ",
        "shop_id": 44,
        "categories_id": 5,
        "category": "category-5",
        "min_price": 555,
        "max_price": 55656,
        "image": "http://cache2.asset-cache.net/gc/129305805-racks-of-clothes-in-a-menswear-store-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=mcPYJ5XyANr2jzh2gHmNDG%2FS5MzSDogxQ%2BKrWHyAnTHGKr%2FOnkBx3JkVNAMcV9GZ",
    },
]
```

and I am looping it like this-

```
 $('.rackLayer').css({"background-image": "url('" + json[0].image + "')"});
            for (z = 1; z < json.length; z++)
            {
                    $('.rackLayer').after("<div class='inside-rack'> </div>");
                    $('.inside-rack').css({"background-image": "url('" + json[z].image + "')"});
            }
```

and the html is-

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="scroll-section">
                    <div class="rackLayer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I want is that image with O index should be added first then remaining images should add after it in order of index 1 and then 2..

Could anyone help?

Comment: Why are you skipping the first index?

Comment: you should remove the `,` after the image url

Comment: I have already added the first index before for loop

Comment: how is the html looks like

Comment: @ArunPJohny check the edited post

Comment: @Bart Why should him remove it? It's a JavaScript Object, not a `JSON` string, so the syntax is actually valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to this one:

```
for (z = 1; z < json.length; z++)
{
   var div = $("<div >", { //<---creates div element
      class  :'inside-rack', 
      'style':'background-image:url("'+ json[z].image +'")' // <--style the bgimg
   });
   $('.rackLayer').after(div); //<---now push in the DOM.
}
```

issue seems to me the selector, `$('.inside-rack')` this would change for all the divs. when loop ends each gets the last object's image property from the json.
So, the solution is to create a new element style it there then push it in DOM.

Comment: but here the order of image according to index is 0,2,1. It should add like 0,1,2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$('.inside-rack').css({"background-image": "url('" + json[z].image + "')"});` which applies the background image to all the previously added elements, instead you need to target the newly created element only.

```js
json = [{
  "id": 6,
  "name": "rac2 ",
  "shop_id": 4,
  "categories_id": 5,
  "category": "category-5",
  "min_price": 555,
  "max_price": 55656,
  "image": "http://www.shopforshops.com/www/61/files/clothing-racks1.jpg",
}, {
  "id": 64,
  "name": "rac32 ",
  "shop_id": 4,
  "categories_id": 5,
  "category": "category-5",
  "min_price": 555,
  "max_price": 55656,
  "image": "http://ohjoy.blogs.com/.a/6a00d8341c6a0853ef019affb2bbfe970c-800wi",
}, {
  "id": 643,
  "name": "rac32 ",
  "shop_id": 44,
  "categories_id": 5,
  "category": "category-5",
  "min_price": 555,
  "max_price": 55656,
  "image": "http://cache2.asset-cache.net/gc/129305805-racks-of-clothes-in-a-menswear-store-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=mcPYJ5XyANr2jzh2gHmNDG%2FS5MzSDogxQ%2BKrWHyAnTHGKr%2FOnkBx3JkVNAMcV9GZ",
}]


var $layer = $('.rackLayer').css({
  "background-image": "url('" + json[0].image + "')"
});

for (z = 1; z < json.length; z++) {
  $("<div class='inside-rack'></div>").css({
    "background-image": "url('" + json[z].image + "')"
  }).insertAfter($layer);
  $('.rackLayer').after();
}
```

```css
.rackLayer,
.inside-rack {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rackLayer"></div>
```